# Vanishing style in table (Firefox)

Tags: html, http, firefox

I've recently been working on a script that outputs an html page.  When the html page is built and loaded from Jenkins (staged artefact), Firefox removes the style information from the table cells.

Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Build_Metrics</title>
</head>
<body>
<table><tbody>
<tr><td style="width:180px; background-color:white"><b>Build_Metrics</b></td><td style="width:180px; background-color:white"></td></tr>
<tr><td style="width:180px; background-color:#FFFFCC">Builds</td><td style="width:180px; background-color:#FFFFCC">&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td style="width:180px; background-color:#FFFFCC">Last Build</td><td style="width:180px; background-color:lime">SUCCESS</td></tr>
<!--extra rows removed-->
</tbody></table></body></html>
```

Observing Firefox's representation of the page with "Inspect Element", every *td* opening tag is replaced with:

```
<td style="">
```

Saving the source locally and opening the html file in Firefox results in the page rendering as expected.
Opening either page (local or Jenkins hosted) in internet explorer provides a page complete with styles set.

The removed rows from the source don't contain anything that isn't in the provided code (only difference is the string and colours) but contain content that I can't post here.  The full page passes both the [WDG HTML Validator](http://www.htmlhelp.org/tools/validator/direct.html.en) and the [w3c validators](https://validator.w3.org/)  without any warnings or errors.

What might be causing the style string to be replaced with `""`?

If it helps, it is Firefox ESR 38.1.0

If it is a bug in this version of Firefox, is there a workaround?

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:180px; background-color:white"><b>Build_Metrics</b></td>
      <td style="width:180px; background-color:white"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:180px; background-color:#FFFFCC">Builds</td>
      <td style="width:180px; background-color:#FFFFCC">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="width:180px; background-color:#FFFFCC">Last Build</td>
      <td style="width:180px; background-color:lime">SUCCESS</td>
    </tr>
    <!--extra rows removed-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Latest FX is 49 I believe... I do not see the issue in FX48

Comment: @mplungjan unfortunately this is a work environment and the software availiable is restricted, hence the ESR channel Firefox.  (On the plus side, I know that everyone will be using the same version to view it too).

Comment: @mplungjan it's worth noting that the code snippet on this page works fine. (thanks for adding it)

Comment: the workaround could be to use a classname and external CSS